# How to add fancybox to instagram fetch images?

Tags: php, instagram

I have made a code to retreive my images from Instagram using the api , and when i added fancy box to it , its stay working only with one photo , how can i make it work

I took that code from here http://www.webcodo.com/get-your-images-with-instagram-api-and-php/#.UgtpcJI9-So

```
$i = 0; 
$count = 20;
    foreach ($ins_media['data'] as $vm): 
        if($count == $i){ break;}
        $i++;
        $img = $vm['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
        $link = $vm["link"];
    ?>

        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" width="175" style="float:left;" />
        </a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: What does that `$count` stand for?

Comment: there s a $count = 20; its the number of images to show